# How to print a scrollable winforms application which has scrollable textbox vb .net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using VB .NET and I would like to print a scrollable winform which has a scrollable textbox.

I have tried to use the following codes:

```
Private Sub btnPrintForm_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrintForm.Click
    Me.PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
    PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)
End Sub
```

And the print preview shows only half of the winforms, which is not complete.

1) How can I print the winforms (full width and height) although some of the winforms areas are hidden due to scrollable feature? Refer to the screenshot in the following website: [Print error screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/sned3uri5/)

2) What is the recommended method to prompt user to change the page orientation?

3) In my winforms, there is a scrollable textbox. How does it affect my print function and what changes should I do to include everything from the scrollable textbox and the content in the scrollable winforms?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its just me, but you do not print forms.. any more... We used to do this in vb6 and was quite upset when .net initially removed the functionality. Think about re-learning to do printing the .net intended way, physically drawing the document... or using a report writer of some sort.

Comment: Dear @Louis Van Tonder, 

"Think about re-learning to do printing the .net intended way, physically drawing the document"

Could you suggest how can I relearn the printing in .net environment?
In other words, printform is not a solution anymore. Which built-in function do you suggest?

Comment: Maybe this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27404/An-absolute-beginner-s-guide-to-printing-in-NET

Comment: Even in VB6 it would not print the contents of a scrollable textbox that was hidden in the scroll.

Comment: @Matt Wilko, based on your experience, what suggestion you would offer to solve this issue?

Comment: louis van Tonder's suggestion that you physically draw the document is the solution here.

Comment: Dear @MattWilko
I have studied the http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27404/An-absolute-beginner-s-guide-to-printing-in-NETI

I still do not understand how to physically draw the document using PrintDocument.

Do you have an example or tutorial for that?

Comment: @user2150279 - what don't you understand?

Comment: @MattWilko, from the website http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27404/An-absolute-beginner-s-guide-to-printing-in-NET above, it talks about the function of PrintDocument.

1) Using PrintDocument, how to draw the document (including the hidden area in a scrollable winforms) for printing?

2) From the example in that website, can it work if I do not use `Inherits System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`? Once I have used it, it appears to have more errors.

Comment: You have to decide on a layout, and physically create it (draw) it, on a blank page (object). Draw each piece of text, each line, place each graphic...

Comment: @LouisvanTonder, appreciate for your suggestion. Do you have a code example for that flow of program? Does it involve PrintDocument only? Sorry to ask a lot as I am new in VB .NET

Comment: Did you look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27404/An-absolute-beginner-s-guide-to-printing-in-NET ? As I previously posted?

Comment: @LouisvanTonder, I had spent five days studying http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27404/An-absolute-beginner-s-guide-to-printing-in-NET

I know PrintDocument has BeginPrint, QueryPageSettings, PrintPage and EndPrint.

I have posted my questions above few posts before regarding the PrintDocument.

Let me retype here:
1) Using PrintDocument, how to draw the document (including the hidden area in a scrollable winforms) for printing? 
2) From the example in that website, can it work if I do not use `Inherits System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument`? Once I had used it, it has more errors

Comment: I still think you are missing the point. There is no "magic" here... You have to do all the work for creating the document. There is no (take my form and put it onto a printdocument) routine. Decide what you want to print. If you want to print "Hello, my name is Louis", you would: Define a Rectange, Define a brush (your pen), define your font, and supply the string, like so: e.Graphics.DrawString("my name is Louis van Tonder", drawFont, drawBrush, drawRect). See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6.aspx